# Retrieving rows in DataView by its index

Tags: c#, dataview

I have a DataView, which has been sorted in some order. How can I retrieve the values using an index.

Something like this:

```
if(dv.rows[0]["name"]=="xxx")  
{  
  --- do something ---  
}  
else  
  --- something else ---
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following code

Move the sorted DataView to DataTable like

```
DataTable dt = dv.ToTable();
```

Then use

```
if (dt.Rows[0]["name"] == "xxx")
{
  [...]
}
```

It will work.

Answer (score 6):

Did you try:

```
DataRowView rowView = dv[index];
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than converting the whole thing back to a Table, you can work with the DataView directly:

To get a row from a `DataView`, you use the `Item` property, which returns a `DataRowView`, and you can then call `Item` to get at the cells, all of which can be shortened to:

```
// Returns object, so needs to be cast to your required type:
if ((string)dv[0]["CellName"] == "ABCD")
{
  [...]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite know if this is the answer you're looking for:

```
if (dv.Rows[0].Cells["CellName"].Value == "ABCD")
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The direct use of the DataRowView is simpler than converting the dv back to a DataTable (where it probably came from to begin with), I think.
`var currRow = dv[0]; currRow["your_col_name"]?.ToString();`