# Incremental Search Issue WinForms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

(i've appended pictures to be more clear on the issue)

**Background :**

my Customer DGV supports incremental search,
when i search a customer, i write his partial id and the dgv is refreshed with only customers that fit the criteria

in general in my customers DGV when i click a certain line, the customer's data is transferred to checkboxes

**The problem:**

in incremental search, my DGV is refreshed with the data that i mentioned before and when i click a line, instead transferring the customer's data which i see currently on the dgv it transfers the customer's data whom if i wouldn't do an incremental search will be there.

My Incremental Search code  :

```
            DataView dv = new DataView(tabSearchCustomer);
            dv.RowFilter = string.Format("CONVERT({0},System.String) LIKE '%{1}%'", "ID", txtboxSearchCustomer.Text);
            dgvCustomers.DataSource = dv;
```

What can i do to fix the issue ?

Dgv's data gets into Checkboxes: http://www.siz.co.il/my.php?i=221winz1yjgi.png

Incremental Search in action(i chose Carrie Fisher): http://www.siz.co.il/my.php?i=atyenz4ij3y1.png

The problem: http://www.siz.co.il/my.php?i=nyfymngxmgkx.png

Comment: Could you also show the code used for selecting and displaying these customers? It sounds like an indexing issue. Most likely nothing wrong with the incremental code.

Comment: This Is My Code :

http://image.prntscr.com/image/f4b2d86fe9ba4514bc244c99ad02b8e8.png

Comment: Checkout this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/700869/retrieving-rows-in-dataview-by-its-index The problem is, I believe, you are grabbing the index of the table, not the modified view.

Comment: My Incremental Search is used in txtboxSearchCustomer_TextChanged method, and my DGV data which loads to the checkboxes is dgvCustomers_CellClick method (different method). 
So how can i use what you suggested ?

Comment: Instead of `dgvCustomers.DataSource = dv;` try utilizing the ToTable like `dgvCustomers = dv.ToTable();` In one instance it appears you are simply changing the `view` but you are not actually changings the `table` so your problem appears to be your index you assign is based on the index of the `table` and not the view in which you see as the client user. It is like if I said I had an array, and said I only want that array to DISPLAY the item at index 3, but then told the view to select index 1 -- because to ME it's index 1, but not to the array.

Comment: I can't use dgvCustomers = dv.ToTable(); , It's say : Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataTable' to 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView'.

And  using dgvCustomers.DataSource = dv.ToTable(); didn't work either